# how to ignore tabindex and put focus on specified field

Tags: c#, winforms

There are a number of winforms controls in different GroupBoxes. In some cases, I need to ignore defined tab indexes and put focus on a specified control in another GroupBox. I've tried to override `ProcessCmdKey` and call `Focus` and `Select` methods but it still following tabindex order. How can i come over tabindexes

Comment: What's wrong with [`myControlThatNeedsFocus.Focus()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: It's just not working - focus still folowing tabindex) and Select method too

Comment: Then you may need to better clarify your question, as written the answer to "How to I put focus on a specific control?" is "Call the `Focus` method on the control in question."

Comment: See my answer, `ProcessTabKey` is what you were missing. This kind of reuqirement isn't unusual so there's a special override just for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have 3 text boxes, textBox1, textBox2 and textBox3:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Tab)
            textBox3.Focus();
    }

    protected override bool ProcessTabKey(bool forward)
    {
        return !textBox1.ContainsFocus && base.ProcessTabKey(forward);
    }
```

This will do exactly what you want. The hey element in this logic is `ProcessTabKey` override, [link to MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processtabkey(v=vs.110).aspx).

Above code makes textBox1 jump to textBox3 instead of letting Windows do it automatically for you.